# bootstrap 3 + font-awesome - why won't this button display the image inline?

Tags: twitter-bootstrap-3, font-awesome

I have a simple logout button in my navbar and I would like the word "Logout" and the icon from font-awesome to display inline.  I thought `<span>` was an inline tag, but it is causing a line break.  I need the span in order to hide the extra text on small screens.

```
<a href="/logout/" type="button" class="btn btn-default navbar-btn pull-right">
  <span class="hidden-xs">Logout</span><i class="fa fa-sign-out fa-lg"></i>
</a>
```

You can see the problem here: http://bootply.com/94625

Answer (score 2, accepted):

try to add:

```
@media(min-width:768px)
{  
.hidden-xs{display:inline !important}
}
```

the .hidden-xs sets the display of your span to block

Comment: It would have taken me all day to figure this out on my own. Thanks.  I'm still not sure why it doesn't work without the @media bit, or why it doesn't work without the !important bit.

Comment: without the media query your .hidden-xs won't be hidden (cause the display will be inline always). !important will be needed cause the .hidden-xs definition use !important too. The only way to overrule !important is with an other !important

Answer (score -1):

It's because you need to download font-awesome and have it in your root directory also point it in your head section. That's because it doesn't show on your live link.

Hope this helps.